# Sum of random variables is measurable - index depends on random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $N:\Omega\to\mathbb{N}$ and $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be independent random variables on a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$. Show that $S_{N}=\sum_{n=1}^{N} X_{n}$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable.

What I tried:

We have to show that for all $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ it follows that $S_{N}^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal{A}$. My idea was to rewrite this preimage as a union of preimages of $N$ and the $X_{i}$, which by definition are $\mathcal{A}$-measurable. Since $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $N(\Omega)\subset\mathbb{N}$, the union has to be countable and therefore lies in $\mathcal{A}$.

Can someone give me a hint how to manipulate $S_{N}^{-1}(A)$ properly to get the result? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{\omega: S_N(\omega) \in E)=\bigcup_n \{\omega: S_n \in E) \cap {\{N=n}\})$. Use the fact that $S_n$ is measurable for each $n$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought in the meantime. Thank you!